# Change grouping of columns in multi index Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

Suppose there is a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['mon', 'mon', 'mon'],
    'fruit': ['apple', 'apple', 'orange'],
    'size': ['big', 'small', 'big'],
    'price': [10, 11, 15],
    'amount': [10, 10, 20]
}).set_index('day')

df = df.groupby(['day', 'fruit', 'size'])['price', 'amount'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack(level=[2])

                        price          amount
size             big    small    big    small
day fruit                   
mon apple   0   10.0     11.0   10.0     10.0
   orange   0   15.0      NaN   20.0      NaN
```

I want to change order of columns from price->big/small, amount->big/small to big->price/amount, small->price/amount. So the expected dataframe is:

```
                           big           small
size             price  amount   price  amount
day fruit                   
mon apple   0   10.0     10.0   11.0     10.0
   orange   0   15.0       20    Nan      NaN
```

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `swaplevel` and `sort_index`

```
df_swap = df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True,False])

Out[840]:
size           big        small
             price amount price amount
day fruit
mon apple  0  10.0   10.0  11.0   10.0
    orange 0  15.0   20.0   NaN    NaN
```